# How to dynamically resize Heap data structure implementation when inserting past capacity

Tags: c++, arrays, heap

I am implementing Heap from scratch. I have a `HEAP` object that contains three fields `int capacity`, `int size`, and `Element *element`, in which we will maintain a max heap of. I support the basic heap functions, but my `insert` is messed up-- whenever I want to insert into a heap that is already at max capacity, I want to dynamically allocate more memory and add it to the heap.

Here are my files

heap.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H
 

struct Element {
    int key;
};

class HEAP {
    public:
    HEAP ();
    HEAP (int, int, Element[]);
    HEAP (int, int, int);
    HEAP (int, int);
    ~HEAP(void);
    void Insert(HEAP, int);
    
    int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    void setSize(int n) {
        size = n;
    }

    void sizeUp() {
        size++;
    }

    void sizeDown() {
        size--;
    }

    int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    int upCapacity() {
        capacity++;
    }
    
    Element getElement(int n) {
        return element[n - 1];
    }

    void setElementKey(int node, int key) {
        this->element[node - 1].key = key;
    }

    void setElement(int node,  Element i_element) {
        this->element[node - 1] = i_element;
    } 

    int getParent(int node) {
        if (node == 1)
            return NULL;
        else
            return floor(node/2);
    }

    Element getParentElement(int node) {
       return this->getElement(this->getParent(node));
    }

    bool parent_has_two_children(int node) {
        if (this->size >= this->getParent(node)*2+1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    Element getRightChildElement(int node) {
        return this->getElement(2 * node + 1);
    }

    int getRightChild(int node) {
        if (2 * node + 1 <= this->size)
            return node * 2 + 1;
        else
            return INT_MAX;
    }

    Element getLeftChildElement(int node) {
        return this->getElement(2 * node);
    }

    int getLeftChild(int node) {
        if (node * 2 <= this->getSize())
            return node * 2;
        else
            return INT_MAX;
    }

    bool isElement(int node) {
        if (node <= this->size)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    void swapWithParent(int node) {
        Element parent_element = this->getParentElement(node);
        this->setElement(this->getParent(node), this->getElement(node));
        this->setElement(node, parent_element);
        return;
    }

    // Swap with right and return node of where orginal element is
    int swapWithRightChild(int node) {
        Element current_element = this->getElement(node);
        this->setElement(node, this->getRightChildElement(node));
        this->setElement(this->getRightChild(node), current_element);
        return this->getRightChild(node);
    }

    // swap with left and return node of where orginal element is
    int swapWithLeftChild(int node) {
        Element current_element = this->getElement(node);
        this->setElement(node, this->getLeftChildElement(node));
        this->setElement(this->getLeftChild(node), current_element);
        return this->getLeftChild(node);
    }

    private:
    int capacity;
    int size;
    Element *element;
}; 

HEAP Initialize(int n);

void BuildHeap(HEAP& heap, Element A[], int n);

void InsertHelper(HEAP&,  Element);
void Insert(HEAP& heap, int flag, int k); 

int DeleteMax(HEAP& heap, int flag); //need flag

void IncreaseKey(HEAP& heap, int flag, int index, int value); // need flag

void PrintHeap(HEAP);

void Heapify(HEAP&, int);
void Sort_Heap(HEAP&);

#endif  /* HEAP_H */
```

heap.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

#include "heap.h"
#include "debug.h"

HEAP::HEAP(int h_capacity, int h_size, Element h_element[]) {
    capacity = h_capacity;
    size = h_size;
    element = new Element[h_capacity];
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < h_size ; i ++) {
        element[i] = h_element[i];
    }
}

HEAP::HEAP() {  
}

HEAP::HEAP(int h_capacity, int h_size) {
    capacity = h_capacity;
    element = new Element[h_capacity];
    size = h_size;
}

HEAP::~HEAP(void) {
    element = new Element[1];
    delete[] element;
}

HEAP Initialize(int h_capacity) {
    HEAP return_heap(h_capacity, 0);
    return return_heap;
}

void BuildHeap(HEAP &i_heap, Element a[], int size) {
    ...
}

void InsertHelper(HEAP &i_heap, Element i_element) {
    // Inset to last element of the Heap
    i_heap.sizeUp();
    i_heap.setElement(i_heap.getSize(), i_element);
    
    // DEBUG STATMENT
    // PrintHeap(i_heap);
}

void Heapify(HEAP &i_heap, int element) {
    ...
}

void Insert(HEAP &i_heap, int flag, int key) {
    // Make the new element
    if (flag != 1 && flag != 2) {
        cout << "Error: invalid flag value\n";
        return; 
    }

    if (flag == 2) {
        cout << "Before insert operation:\n";
        PrintHeap(i_heap);
    }

    Element new_element;
    new_element.key = key;
    
    // Insert the new element into the Heap
    InsertHelper(i_heap, new_element);

    for(int i = floor(i_heap.getSize() / 2); i >= 1 ; i--) {
        Heapify(i_heap, i);
    }

    if (flag == 2) {
        cout << "Before insert operation:\n";
        PrintHeap(i_heap);
    }
}

int DeleteMax(HEAP &i_heap, int flag){
    ...
}

void IncreaseKey(HEAP &i_heap, int flag, int element, int key) {
    ...
}

void PrintHeap(HEAP i_heap) {
    ...
}
```

It looks like a lot of code, but we are mostly looking at the `Insert` and `InsertHelper` functions. How can I modify them as to allow dynamic allocation when hitting capacity? I've tried to completely reinitalize the heap object and copy the elements within it, but I believe some pointer issues are present, as I cannot copy the `Element* element*` array successfully into the new `NewHeap` with the `newCapacity = oldcapacity * 2`. I'd appreciate any help. I do not want to use vectors-- I am trying to implement that myself.

I am doing

```
void Insert(HEAP &i_heap, int flag, int key)
{
    //Make the new element
    if (flag != 1 && flag != 2)
    {
        cout << "Error: invalid flag value\n";
        return;
    }
    if (flag == 2)
    {
        cout << "Before insert operation:\n";
        PrintHeap(i_heap);
    }
    Element new_element;
    new_element.key = key;
    if (i_heap.getCapacity() <= i_heap.getSize())
    {
        Element *newElement = new Element[i_heap.getCapacity() * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < i_heap.getSize(); i++)
        {
            newElement[i] = i_heap.getElement(i);
        }
        i_heap.setElementArray(newElement);
    }

    //Insert the new element into the Heap
    InsertHelper(i_heap, new_element);

    for (int i = floor(i_heap.getSize() / 2); i >= 1; i--)
    {
        Heapify(i_heap, i);
    }
    if (flag == 2)
    {
        cout << "Before insert operation:\n";
        PrintHeap(i_heap);
    }
}
```

in my `Insert` function, but it gives me this

```
project2(1588,0x1131d1e00) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd422504080: pointer being freed was not allocated

project2(1588,0x1131d1e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Comment: It should be as simple as `Element *newElement = new Element[capacity * 2];` followed by a for-loop to copy from `element` to `newElement`, deleting `element`, then `element = newElement`

Comment: Are you saying you're for some reason unable to do that? If so, what's wrong with it? What error are you getting?

Comment: @rkechols I've edited my post to include what happens

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of problems in the code you posted.
I will try to focus on the bigger ones

The first point is **your heap management**, it **is really poor of checks**, it **is not safe**.
Let's take a look to your InsertHelper function by commenting what the code does.

```
void InsertHelper(HEAP &i_heap, Element i_element)
{
    i_heap.sizeUp(); // Moving Up an int representing the size of the Heap
    i_heap.setElement(i_heap.getSize(), i_element); // Assigning to the supposed last element the new value

}
```

Now let's write a small code make evident what checks are missing.

```
int main()
{
    HEAP h = Initialize(0); //initializing HEAP with capacity 0
    InsertHelper(h, Element()); //moving size to 1 (only size, not capacity) 
                                //and assigning Element[0] with value : is the access to Element[0] safe? 
    return 0;
}
```

This small example is showing how the access to the elements in the heap aren't safe enough.
The first thing we can notice is that sizeUp is just incrementing an int (size) that it represents the size of the heap, but sizeUp isn't really adding nothing to the Element array allocated in the heap using new keyword in your constructor.
In short your sizeUp is just incrementing size, without checking if capacity is enough, and without increasing capacity (and without reallocating the array of Element).

The second thing is that setElement used by InsertHelper is accessing to an element that is supposed to be a valid element of the dynamically allocated array but without checking if this supposed condition is true. In short you are not checking if the index of the element you are accessing is < of heap's size and capacity.

Let's remove all the function call and paste your implicit code, converting the
previous code in something much easier to read.

```
int main()
{
    
    //HEAP h = Initialize(0);  <--- become like
    int Size = 0; //this is an internal value
    int Capacity = 0; //this is an internal value
    Element* ElementPtr = new Element[0]; // this is an internal value
    
    //InsertHelper(h, Element()); <--- become like
    Size++; // increasing the internal value of size by one
    ElementPtr[0] = Element(); // accessing to the first element of the internal array
}
```

Hope you can easily notice where the problem lies, this code doesn't work.
The access to the Element in position 0 (the first element) cause the program to crash, basically because the memory you are accessing isn't allocated.
In short the point is: Check if you are accessing to a valid element, by checking the index passed to the function setElement to be < of the size of the array.

Let's move to another point.
This point was implicit in the previous one, but we are here to make things explicit and easy to understand.
**Size should never exceed capacity, and capacity must represent the real -dynamically allocated- internal array size.**

By reading again the code above you can notice that size is moved to 1 while capacity is still 0, and your internal array is still empty.
All these steps would be good to be internal checked, using a private method, probably named _ReserveCapacity (just an example).

The Third point is the cleaning up of your HEAP object.
**The destructor is causing Memory Leak**.

```
HEAP::~HEAP(void)
{
    element = new Element[1];
    delete[] element;
}
```

The correct way of doing what you was trying is:

```
HEAP::~HEAP()
{
    if(element)
        delete[] element;
}
```

The problem with your destructor is the fact that it is causing, in many cases but not in all the case since you got an empty constructor - but this is explained in point 4- , **Memory Leak**
you can learn more about the memory leak [here](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) if you wish.

We can easly summarise the reason by writing a really small main and commenting it with what code is doing.

```
int main()
{
    HEAP h(100);// using new to allocate 100 Elements
//here destructor is called and it again allocate 1 element and delete it
}

//are the first ones 100 elements never deleted?
```

In this case you can notice that they are two allocations using **new** and only one deleting using **delete[]**. It sounds wrong.
In this case you are leaving the first ones 100 Elements allocated in the Heap and you are also losing the unique way you got to identify the address where they are stored by overriding the value of the **Element* element** internal value that stores it.
In short Leak is happening and that memory can't never be deleted, till the program ends its running.

I want to limit me with the fourth and last point to don't get you too confused, I think these 4 are the worst mistakes.

**The empty constructor**

```
HEAP::HEAP()
{  
}
```

the right way is:

```
HEAP::HEAP()
{
    capacity = 0;
    size = 0;
    element = nullptr; //<-- or NULL if you are using a really old c++ standard
}
```

In this case you are creating a new HEAP object that is a time bomb ready to explode.
The internal values arent initialized at all, and this is a big problem.
What does it happen in the moment i will use an InsertHelper on this HEAP object?
You can't leave to the user that is working with your HEAP class the hard task to select the right constructor (that really initialize the object) but making available one that doesn't initialize any value at all.

Any usage of this constructor (obtained by just writing HEAP h;) will get us an object with random values of size, random values of capacity, and a random value for the pointer *element that store the address of memory we are working with.

In short the point is that this object looks like to be initialzied, with a non zero size, a non zero capacity and a non zero address, but no, it isn't initialized and any use of it will make our program crash.

So any constructor should initialize all the members of a class, in order to don't get any random value that will cause problems.

---

EDIT:

However, I also want to add a direct and simple answer to the question in the title.

let's assume we have a main of this type:

```
int main()
{
    HEAP h(0);
    h.Insert(0, Element());
    return 0;
}
```

I changed the behaviour of your Insert making it starts counting element positions by 0 (your code was starting by 1).
In this case we are going to insert an element in an HEAP object that looks actually empty.

**What are the steps your insert should follow to make it works correcly?**

- It **checks** if the HEAP object own enough space.
- It **assigns** the value once HEAP object own the space.

An example of Insert function would be:

```
void HEAP::Insert(int position, const Element& value)
{
    _CheckSpace(position);
    element[position] = value;
}



void HEAP::_CheckSpace(int position)
{
    if(size < position)
    {
        if(capacity < position)
            _ReserveCapacity(position);
        
        size = position;
    }
}


void HEAP::_ReserveCapacity(int count)
{
    //allocating the new array in the heap
    auto new_space = new Element[count];
    
    //copyng and deleting the ole array
    if(element)
    {
        //copying all the elements with a for loop
        //this step would be faster using a memcpy
        //but only when the array element type
        //doesn't own heap allocations itself
        for(int i=0; i < size < count ? size : count; i++)
            new_space[i] = element[i];
        //deleting the old array
        delete[] element;
    }
    
    capacity = count;
    element = new_space;
}
```